# Does windows 10 enable anything be default that would produce a log of delete files?

Tags: windows-10, security, file-management, logging

I have a scenario where it would be useful to demonstrate that nothing (or nothing useful anyway) has been deleted from a disk drive in a Windows 10 environment.

Would Windows 10 have anything enabled by default that would create such a log or would any such log only be created after deliberate settings adjustment?

Comment: This type of logging must be enabled, the logging that would cover this behavior, is not enabled by default.  If it wasn't enabled when the files were deleted, nothing was logged, obviously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I log file operations (create/modify/delete) in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/402792/can-i-log-file-operations-create-modify-delete-in-windows), also consider [File Auditing in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/521945/file-auditing-in-windows)